# What does the colon operator in an expr do?

Tags: shell, syntax, pattern-matching, matching

I am looking at a shell script someone wrote and they wrote this:

```
expr "$myvariable" : '0*$'
```

What does this mean?

Comment: already saw that entry and it's not a duplicate, AFAIK

Comment: Exactly which shell is running this?  Bash, csh, Kornshell...?

Comment: Bash, sorry...should have been more clear

Comment: Good, then I can test my half-written answer before I embarrass myself...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The colon : in an expr is a matching operator.  The strings on the left is tested against a regex on the right.  Whatever matches is caught by the regex group ( ).  The regex replaces itself with a count of characters, then the : acts kind of like an array indexing operation - you get the left-side string from that location onward (like somestring[n:] in Python)

The '0*$' is matching a zero, any stuff, end of line.  I don't know what's in myvariable, but I guess no fireworks unless its value starts with a zero character.

An example of a similar line of shell script - except in assigning the result to a variable, and different specific strings - is explained in http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch36_23.htm (from O'Reilly Unix Power Tools)

See also http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/expr.html  about halfway down

Comment: Yup that's what this is doing...although in your answer you said its value starts with a zero...but i think you mean ends with a zero.